What is this dark mark inside my model?
I remeshed a text file by hand and then operated a boolean difference exclusion.
Now I see dark shape s inside my model that I can't understand. The Model and topology seem fine though.

Also here.

I tried applying scale and cleaning up normals but I can't understand.
What is this darkness inside the shape and how can I fix it?

The comment to use Object Data Properties > Geometry Data > Clear Custom Split Normals Data on my other question helped

It looks like for some reason the split normals are just messed up on this part, click on the Clear Custom Split Normals Data button under Data > Geometry Data:

